# Iterate through command line arguments in Bash

Tags: bash

Can someone explain the difference between these two code blocks? I would think Block #2 would output the same as Block #1 but it does not. Can someone explain why?

```
# ./arguments.sh hello my name is X
```

Block #1

```
for i
do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
hello
my
name
is
X
```

Block #2

```
args=$#
for (( i=1; i<=$args; i+=1 ))
do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Replace in second example `echo $i` by `echo $i $1; shift` to get more confused or enlightened.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, I also found `while (( "$#" )); do echo $1; shift; done` It served its purpose; confusion. I would still like to know why Block #2 does not produce the same output as Block #1 :)

Comment: @jes516 in #2, you are *explicitly* creating a variable `i` and assigning an integer index to it; in #1, the shell is *implicitly* assigning each **positional parameter** in turn to `i`. See the `for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done` construct in the `Compound commands` section of `man bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252916/80216) answers the question that you actually asked:

> **Q:** What is the difference between these two code blocks? 
>   Why do they give different output?
>
> **A:** The first loop is iterating over the command line arguments;
>   the second one is iterating over the argument *numbers* (indices).

... although I presume that you would have figured that much out
for yourself in another six to eight minutes — it's kind-of obvious.
You probably want the second program to do something like

```
echo $$i                                        # This doesn't do what you want.
```

to display the argument that is indexed by the number
that is stored in variable `i` (and referenced as `$i`). 
As noted in the comment, that doesn't do what you want. 
(It *does* do something;
I encourage you to experiment and figure out *what* it does.) 
But this is close to something that does work:

```
eval echo \$$i                                  # Don't do this.
```

or, equivalently,

```
eval echo '$'"$i"                               # Don't do this.
```

These commands

- get the value of `i` (one of the numbers 1, 2, 3, ...)
- stick a `$` in front of it, forming `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.
- use the `eval` command to say, "take this command line
  that I've just constructed, and **eval**uate it as if I had typed it.

So that would have the effect of executing

```
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
   ︙
```

But, as the comments suggest, you should try to avoid this. 
`eval` can be dangerous if the input is anything other than plain words. 
Search this site; you'll find plenty of explanations of that.

But there is a fairly safe way to get the second program
to do the same thing the first one does: change

```
echo $i
```

to

```
echo ${!i}
```

OK, first of all, `${i}` is pretty much the same as `$i`. 
The `!` gives you an effect similar to that of the `eval` command —
`${!x}` looks up the value of `x` (i.e., `$x` or `${x}`)
and uses *that* as the name of the variable to look up. 
So, if `x=foo`, then `${!x}` is the same as `$foo`. 
The above code does the same thing with `i`,
fetching the parameter whose name is the value of `i`.

By the way, you should always quote all references to shell variables
(e.g., `"$i"`, `"$#"`, `"$args"`, `"${i}"` and `"${!i}"`)
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: Just so I am clear, bash is looking for the variable `$1`, `$2`, etc... where the dollar sign is part of the variable name. For example I did, `args="$#"; a="$1"; b="$2"; echo "${a}"; echo "${b}"` and that worked. I thought bash was looking for the variable `1`, `2`, etc... where the dollar sign was part of the syntax (for lack of better terms).

Comment: I'd say you were right the first time.  If you have a variable named `a`, at the risk of being redundant, its name is `a`.  You set it by saying `a=…`; e.g., `a=aardvark` or `a="$1"`.  You _access_ it (e.g., in an `echo` command) with `"$a"` or `"${a}"`, so the `$` and `${…}` are part of the syntax (and that’s a perfectly appropriate term).  `$1`, `$2`, etc… are _slightly_ different from `$a`, `$b`, etc…, but not much.

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate the insight. While I have your attention (if you don't mind) why does `for i; do echo $i; done` work as well to print arguments? Does bash automatically run that code block for each argument? I am used to seeing `for i in list; ...`

Comment: You understand `for i in "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"; do …`, right?  But the problem is that you don’t know in advance how many arguments there are (i.e., how many there are going to be).  [roaima’s answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252916/80216) brushed up against this without delving into it.  `$@` (which, above all other `$` expressions, should ***always*** be quoted) is a magic token that expands to the list of arguments, however long or short that is. (You can, and should, read about this, the `${…}` syntax, and other things in sh/bash documentation;  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  e.g., what you get if you type `man sh` or `man bash` (if that doesn’t work for you, try [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)), the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), the POSIX specification for [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), and other references.)  And `for i; do …` is a special shorthand for `for i in "$@"; do …` — which is equivalent to `for i in "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"; do …` (if you have five arguments).

Answer (score 8):

The first block iterates (implicitly) across the command line arguments `"$@"`

```
for i in "$@"    # same as your "for i"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The second block iterates explicitly across the number of arguments, printing the index as it goes:

```
args=$#                          # number of command line args
for (( i=1; i<=$args; i+=1 ))    # loop from 1 to N (where N is number of args)
do
    echo $i
done
```

Given that, as per your example, `$#` is 5, then the `$i` variable will take the values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.

As pointed out in another (now deleted) answer, you can reference the command line arguments by index like this:

```
args=$#
for (( i=1; i<=$args; i++ ))
do
    echo "$i - ${!i}"
done
```

Comment: Just to expand on my comment below, `echo "$i - ${!i}"` is echoing the variable `i` - the variable `$i`, where `i` is the number and `$i` evaluates to the "shell variable" `$1`..